# How to paint color on different part of an object?

Tags: color

I have a long object (a leg bone). The object consists of two parts (left and right) which are divided by a non-manifold plane (zero thickness). I would like to ask if there is any way to paint the right part with different color than the left part without "cutting" the object by Boolean modifier?

Thank you[image: My object]

Comment: are you using texture painting or vertex painting?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't really understand the tool you are mentioning. I'm very new to blender. I just want to paint different color on each part.

Comment: here's a video on the very basics of materials, you can assign different colored materials do different faces of your mesh to make them different colors. https://youtu.be/nBdGm_d_8XE